# Mysql and PDO: Insert With Select and Parameter

Tags: mysql, pdo

Is it possible to put a parameter value into a select statement for an insert?  I haven't had much success trying to figure this out.

I obviously know the query below is wrong but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Query

```
 INSERT INTO test
 SELECT other.col1, other.col2, :somevalue
 FROM other
```

Comment: Is `:somevalue` intended to be a string literal rather than a column name? In other words are you doing `SELECT col1, col2, 'a string' FROM other` or are you trying to use a dynamic column name `SELECT col1, col2, unknowncol3 FROM other`?

Comment: Can you describe in a little more specific detail what you are selecting, and what the result inserted should be?

Comment: Yes, :somevalue is intended to be a string literal, not a column name.

Comment: I expect what you have would work then. Is it not working? And if not, what error do you get?

Comment: The error I get is:  Insert value list does not match column list

Comment: Ohhhhh -  you forgot your column list `INSERT INTO test (col1, col2, col3) SELECT col1, col2, :somevalue FROM other` Sorry I missed that :)

Comment: I'll put it in as a proper answer below.

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting is syntactically valid and should work correctly.  Unless the target table has exactly the same number of columns, the `INSERT` statement must include a columns list:

```
INSERT INTO test (col1, col2, col3) 
  SELECT col1, col2, :somevalue
  FROM other
```

Note that this syntax works with a PDO bound parameter because `:somevalue` is meant to be a string literal. If you had been hoping instead for `:somevalue` to be a dynamically determined *column name* rather than a sting, that would not work as intended - you'd get a literal string value instead of a column name.